# Google Maps Javascript API-Requests

Tags: google-maps-api-3

The free requests for google maps Javascript API is 25,000 requests/day. Can anyone please elaborate on what is considered as a "request" while usage of google maps? Is it the number of map loads or interactions made with the map (zoom in,out,markers or so) or anything else?

Answer (score 3):

According to [the doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage), you are allowed to have 25,000 map loads by day.

A **[map load](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_mapload)** is defined as :

> A single map load occurs when:
>
> - A map is displayed using the Maps JavaScript API v3 when loaded by a web page or application;
> - A Street View panorama is displayed using the Maps JavaScript API v3 by a web page or application that has not also displayed a map;
> - A single request is made for a map image from the Static Maps API; or
> - A single request is made for a panorama image from the Street View Image API.
>
> The degree to which a user interacts with a map once it has been loaded has no impact on the usage limits [...]

So, zoom in / out, or number of markers has nothing to do with what you call "request".

Answer (score 0):

License for publicly facing websites is "Free until exceeding 25,000 map loads per day for 90 consecutive days"

Check out full licensing details here: https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/

Answer (score 0):

The number of free requests is going to change drastically..
Until June 11th you can do 25.000 free requests a day, from June 11th it is 28.000 a month!

https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/